# How to enable wake up on Ctrl+Alt+Del only on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sleep, wake-up

How to enable wake up on Ctrl+Alt+Del only on Windows 7?

For the longest time it worked like that for me,
but after I reinstalled the system, the PC started waking up from sleep mode on just touching the mouse or from pressing any key.

Comment: AFAIK, there’s only wake on any key press, not a specific key combination.

Comment: This isn't really true. My PC at work with Windows 8 functions like this right now - it will only wake up on pressing Ctrl+Alt+Deal, it does not wake up on pressing random keys or moving the mouse. Plus as I said I had the exact same behaviour on Win 7 before.